# create polished brass

Tags: materials

Good morning, all.

I'm trying to create a 3D image of my business logo from a 2D.

I'd like the finished product to be Steampunk styled, so I'm going with a weathered wood look background with the logo itself in polished brass on top.

I got the logo extruded and I think it looks fine, but now I need to get it looking like polished brass.

It would probably be easy to "give me a fish" but if you could "teach me to fish", that would be better for me.

Thanks so much for your time.

James

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is not a tutorial site so "teach me to fish" questions are off-topic here. Post what you have tried so far and we may be able to help but there are already many suitable tutorials online if you are prepared to search for them.

Comment: Is the second image what you have done and what it looks like right now? It would help to see a reference of polished brass.

Comment: For polished brass try a *Principled BSDF* node with the Base Color E1C16E (Hex), set Metallic to 1, and Roughness between 0.15 and 0.22. If you want to have to look more antique/weathered you need to mix in some textures. Musgrave is a good choice. Set Lacunarity to something low like 0.3 and Detail high to 9 and you will get something that looks like rust stains.